# What does this black visa rejection stamp from Israel mean?

Tags: passport-stamps, israel, visa-rejections

I had applied for B2 visit visa for Israel. They rejected and marked my passport with the following black stamp:

[image]

What does the black stamp mean and what are its restrictions? Can I reapply and if yes, when should I apply? I plan on reapplying next month. Will that be fine?

Comment: Did you receive a refusal letter? There’s usually no point reapplying unless you can address the refusal reason(s), which typically means providing better evidence or waiting until your circumstances improve before reapplying

Comment: This is not a rejection stamp, this just says a visa application was submitted. Place Nicosia, date 28.6.19. But, as one of the comments on the similar question suggests, maybe the lack of the visa, which should be put in the place of the stamp indicates that the application was rejected.

Comment: From the linked question/answers it might be worth a second try without much changes in between.

Comment: This is not a rejection stamp per se. It says "visa request filed. Place: Nicosia. Date: June 28th 2019."